# Has anyone been able to get data from SharePoint Online (office 365) using SSIS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, office-365

I have been following the example in this site:

http://blog.nhaslam.com/2012/01/26/loading-reference-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-using-ssis/

And everything works just fine if SP is inhouse but when I try to connect to the SharePoint Online (office 365) it's not able to make the connection on step #9.

I get the following message:

> "Error at Data Flow Task [SharePoint List Source [1]];
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
>   request was forbidden with client authenigcation schema 'Ntlm'...."

This is clearly due to authentication.

What is credentials format? I tried `<domain>\<user>` and `<email>`, but nothing seems to work. I don't think Ntlm would be supported for SP online but I may be wrong.

So is this even possible? Or is there another option to get this data using SSIS?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: are you able to create a back-up of the SP database locally and SSIS from there? I seem to remember SSIS not being supported but I can't find any documentation

Comment: I guess that could be an option, but sharePoint backup is also not very trivial, and all I want is a couple fields out of a list, taking a backup and then reading from it seems a little too much work.

Answer (score 4):

NTLM is not supported for SharePoint online. You have to use the [OData API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx) which requires OAuth authentication. Out of the box, SSIS will not support this and you will have to write CLR code if you are going to try.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i have been doing this...

i use

- a claims class for authentication
- a custom SSIS script task, with parameters for username, password etc.
- connect to an oData feed (either json or atom)
- i then use CSOM to populate termstores or SharePoint lists